# How would I get the URL after my own URL?

Tags: php

I'm designing a website where the user would enter a URL after my one and then I would return values from that webiste.

An example would be

> www.mydomain.com/www.Iwanttogetthis.com

How would I go about getting this URL when the page loads?

Thank you

Comment: I guess it would be something like `www.mydomain.com?url=www.iwanttogetthis.com` unless you are using something like url rewriting

Comment: I've tried PHP Get functions but because its technicality seen a new page I don't know how to create a new page based on what the User enters.  Sorry what do you mean by format?

Comment: You also need to URL-encode characters so you can distinguish which URL they belong to, for example: `www.mydomain.com?url=www%2eiwanttogetthis%2ecom`. That's especially important if the URL contains ?, & or /. You can sometimes get away without doing this, but it's not reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use URL rewrite to rewrite that part into a parameters.

More informations (for apache) here : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: Who said OP is using Apache?

Comment: @Azrael Apache or not, he should use URL rewriting. I've provided a link for apache because it's widely used, but he's free to lookout the web (or SO) for other http servers.

Comment: Thank you.  For anyone looking for a good tutorial on URL Rewriting there is a good [Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oqg6Chk6L7M).